# Remove shiny icon backgrounds from Ubuntu Dock / Dash to Dock

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dash-to-dock

I'm using dash-to-dock extension and `dconf-tools` on Ubuntu 18.04 but I dunno what particular setting I need to change to make the background of an icon always black and without that little "shadow" or how should I call it at the top of it:

[image: my dock so far]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch Terminal and run the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock unity-backlit-items false
```